# How can I add a shadow/fade for my views?

Tags: android, listview, fade, shadow

The ListView has a nice fade on the top/bottom.

I have a ListView in the top half of my app, and then a ViewFlipper on the bottom. Is it possible to add a fade/shadow to the top of the ViewFlipper? This would look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lay a `View` on top of the `ViewFlipper` or you can change the background of the `ViewFlipper` and adjust the top padding.

Comment: Would the background of my ViewFlipper be the shadow graphic? Can you explain a little more?